# Cypher: What is the best way to match subgraphs based on several ASCII-snippets?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I'm learning Cypher/Neo4j and am playing around with the movie graph dataset.
I would like to understand how to write statements that match more complicated subgraphs *and return the entire subgraph.*

For example, if I want the subgraphs of people who have acted in and directed the same movie, I can use:

```
MATCH (m:Movie) <-[:DIRECTED]-(p:Person) -[:ACTED_IN]-> (m:Movie)
RETURN *
```

However, this only works because the subgraph I'm looking for is a straight line. If I wanted to expand the above to match subgraphs of people who both A: directed a movie they acted in and B: acted in a particular movie - "Movie X", I would not know how to do this. I understand I could use a WHERE statement to filter out subgraphs where the actor did not act in "Movie X", but this would not return the node representing "Movie X".

I'm wondering if there's a way to construct such queries - something like the below:

```
MATCH (p:Person) -[:ACTED_IN]-> (m:Movie) AND
(p:Person) -[:DIRECTED]-> (m:Movie) AND
(p:Person)-[:ACTED_IN]->(:Movie {title: 'Movie X'})
RETURN *
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are absolutely on the right path. Give this a try

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[:ACTED_IN]->(m:Movie)
WHERE (p)-[:DIRECTED]->(m)
AND (p)-[:ACTED_IN]->(:Movie {title: 'Movie X'})
RETURN *
```

In this case since you already know that you want people that acted in Movie X, a better approach in this specific case would be to match 'Movie X' right off the hop such as...

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[:ACTED_IN]->(m:Movie {title: 'Movie X'})
WHERE (p)-[:DIRECTED]->(m)
RETURN *
```

In order to return 'Movie X' (although it should be one of the movies already matched you need to identify it in a `MATCH` statement. YOu could do something like this...

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[:ACTED_IN]->(m:Movie)
WHERE (p)-[:DIRECTED]->(m)
WITH p, m
MATCH (p)-[:ACTED_IN]->(m2:Movie {title: 'Movie X'})
RETURN p, m, m2
```

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't work, as it doesn't return the node representing "Movie X", unfortunately.

Comment: interesting. It is redundant, you could just match 'Movie X' in the first line, but it should work.

Comment: I understand the "Movie X" condition doesn't provide any extra information in this case. However, I'd just like to be able to control whether the node is returned or not. For instance if I wanted to return nodes represented movies p acted in that were released after year 2000, it'd be important to also return the node.

Comment: The query in the edit is different from what I'm attempting, though. I'm looking for subgraphs where a person p has acted in + directed ANY movie m, and has acted in a particular movie "Movie X".
The first identifies the correct cases, but it doesn't return the node corresponding to both movies.

Comment: Ah, the third one is exactly what I'm looking for. I wasn't aware you could 'chain together' several MATCH statements. Thanks a bunch!